# Serializing a Queue Object as an argument in Celery task

Tags: serialization, queue, celery

I have a Celery based Application.

This application contains 3 different celery processes.
But I have a problem here that i am not able to share data across the 3 processes.

Explored the use of Pickle for queues but dint quite work well.

Basically all i need is to have a Queue object passed as Argument to the Celery Tasks.

And After successful exit of the Processes, should be able to read/write the Queue.

Any help would be great.

---

Cheers
Arun.

Comment: I am using RMQ for queuing celery tasks. Can RMQ queues be used in this case to share data.

Comment: no, multiprocessing.Queue object is not picklable.

Comment: So in this case, what is the best way to use to share data across processes.

Comment: why you want inter-worker communication, what is your initial problem then? to share data, you could use a dedication storage service.